# ValueError with Sklearn LinearRegression model.predict()

Tags: sklearn-pandas

I am trying to do a simple linear regression model to estimate the sales price of an item for borrowers we don't have contract information on. I'm using data from borrowers we do have price and payment info on and using sklearn's `LinearRegression` model but getting an error when I call the `predict()` method on the model. The exact error:

`ValueError: X has 844 features, but LinearRegression is expecting 2529 features as input.`

Here is my code, I feel like it's fairly straightforward. The `build_customer_df` is a method call that returns the dataframe with some column formatting, nothing fancy:
`

```
fp = Path('master_borrower.xlsx')

df = build_customer_df(fp)

df = df[['payment', 'trailer_sales_price']]
df = df[df['payment']!= 0]

X = df['payment'].values
y = df['trailer_sales_price'].values


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=1)

X_test = X_test.reshape(1,-1)
X_train = X_train.reshape(1,-1)
y_train = y_train.reshape(1,-1)
y_test = y_test.reshape(1,-1)

model = linear_model.LinearRegression()

model.fit(X_train, y_train)


predictions = model.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: Hi! Could you provide a minimal reproducible example of `df` dataframe?

Comment: Hello @cucurbit, It's a pandas dataframe with two columns of floats. 3373 rows by 2 columns 
And I apologize if that's not the answer you're looking for, this is my first time asking a question and I am not familiar with what exactly you may be asking for